# Deck of Cards, pick a random card and use two arrays

Tags: arrays, class

Okay I am creating a Deck of Cards, as many others have asked and I can get all the cards to show up in my code, but the problem is that they are in the same order each time. I have gotten the card class down how my professor wants it, but the Deck class is my problem. A few things, she wanted us to use enumerated for the suit, and she wanted us to put the set methods in private to see why we shouldn't do that. (Don't ask me how that makes any sense, but it's what she wanted) The instructions on it say:

The Deck constructor will build an array of all 52 Card objects. That is, it will build the Card objects. It should have an array parallel to the array that indicates whether the card has been removed from the deck. It should have a method to pick a random card from the deck. This method will remove and return a card.

I am just stuck at the parallel array part, how do I get it to check if something was removed from the original array? And how should I approach pick the random card?

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Here is my code also:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

enum suit { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES };

class Card
{
friend class Deck;
private:

string rankname[14];
string suitname;
int rank;
int suitnum;
suit s;

void privatesetsuit(suit arg_suit)
{
    s = arg_suit;
}

void privatesetrank(int arg_rank)

{
    rank = arg_rank;
}
public:


Card()
{
}

void setsuit(suit arg_suit)
{
    privatesetsuit(arg_suit);
}

void setrank(int arg_rank)
{
    privatesetrank(arg_rank);
}

int getsuit()
{
return s;
}

int getrank()
{
return rank;
}

void toString()
{
    rankname[1] = "ACE";
    rankname[2] = "TWO";
    rankname[3] = "THREE";
    rankname[4] = "FOUR";
    rankname[5] = "FIVE";
    rankname[6] = "SIX";
    rankname[7] = "SEVEN";
    rankname[8] = "EIGHT";
    rankname[9] = "NINE";
    rankname[10] = "TEN";
    rankname[11] = "JACK";
    rankname[12] = "QUEEN";
    rankname[13] = "KING";

    if (suitnum == 1)
    {
        suitname = "DIAMONDS";
    }
    if (suitnum == 3)
    {
        suitname = "SPADES";
    }

    if (suitnum == 2)
    {
        suitname = "HEARTS";
    }

    if (suitnum == 0)
    {
        suitname = "CLUBS";
    }

     cout << rankname[rank] << " OF " << suitname << endl;
}
};

void privatesetsuit(int s);
void setsuit(int s);
void privatesetrank(int arg_rank);
void setrank(int arg_rank);
void toString();


class Deck
{   
public:
Deck()
{
    Card currentcard[52];
    Card parallel[52];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        currentcard[i].rank = i % 52;
        currentcard[i].rank = currentcard[i].rank % 13 + 1;
        parallel[i].rank = currentcard[i].rank;
        currentcard[i].suitnum = i % 4;
        currentcard[i].toString();

    }
    }
};


int main()
{
Deck d;
d;


// Test for Class!//
//c.setrank(rank);
//c.setsuit(s);
//c.toString();
// Test for Class!//
}
```

Output:

```
ACE OF CLUBS
TWO OF DIAMONDS
THREE OF HEARTS
FOUR OF SPADES
FIVE OF CLUBS
SIX OF DIAMONDS
SEVEN OF HEARTS
EIGHT OF SPADES
NINE OF CLUBS
TEN OF DIAMONDS
JACK OF HEARTS
QUEEN OF SPADES
KING OF CLUBS
ACE OF DIAMONDS
TWO OF HEARTS
THREE OF SPADES
FOUR OF CLUBS
FIVE OF DIAMONDS
SIX OF HEARTS
SEVEN OF SPADES
EIGHT OF CLUBS
NINE OF DIAMONDS
TEN OF HEARTS
JACK OF SPADES
QUEEN OF CLUBS
KING OF DIAMONDS
ACE OF HEARTS
TWO OF SPADES
THREE OF CLUBS
FOUR OF DIAMONDS
FIVE OF HEARTS
SIX OF SPADES
SEVEN OF CLUBS
EIGHT OF DIAMONDS
NINE OF HEARTS
TEN OF SPADES
JACK OF CLUBS
QUEEN OF DIAMONDS
KING OF HEARTS
ACE OF SPADES
TWO OF CLUBS
THREE OF DIAMONDS
FOUR OF HEARTS
FIVE OF SPADES
SIX OF CLUBS
SEVEN OF DIAMONDS
EIGHT OF HEARTS
NINE OF SPADES
TEN OF CLUBS
JACK OF DIAMONDS
QUEEN OF HEARTS
KING OF SPADES
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I have srand(time(NULL)); in there, because I was originally using rand, but I was getting duplicates of other cards, and I just forgot to take it out. Any improvements to this would be appreciated!

Comment: The parallel array is just a boolean that tells you if the number has been chosen already meaning the card has already been dealt.

Comment: To check if a card was removed, implement a function that will iterate through the cards and check against the rank/suitnum of a supplied card instance.  If none is found that matches, then the card has been removed from the deck.  For shuffling cards, this might help: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/

Comment: @Vizkos, that's costly and not what the specs say. The parallel array doesn't need to be a card array - just to be clear. You're doing to much. Set the entire parallel to false and do `if(!parallel[i]) {...}`. In `{...}` set parallel[i] to true (it's been used) and go on about your day. -- `bool parallel[52];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It should have an array parallel to the array that indicates whether the card has been removed from the deck.

The phrase "indicates whether" is a giveaway that Boolean values are wanted. In your case, this is an array of 52 Boolean values, so `bool is_removed[52];`.

> […] how do I get it to check if something was removed from the original array?

You don't want to check if something was removed from the original array, because you don't actually want to remove anything from the original array. Ever. Instead, to remove a card from the deck, you just set `is_removed[i]` to `true` (where `i` is the appropriate index); and to check if a card has been removed from the deck, you just examine `is_removed[i]`.

Comment: How can I make it check for a specific card? Like "ACE OF SPADES" if ACE is part of the rank and SPADES is part of the enumeration suit? Should I maybe set it to where it becomes a string after it finds the rank and suit and just make an array of strings with each their own specific card?

Comment: @AustinHolbrook: Given that your teacher describes randomly selecting and removing a card from the deck, I gather that she is *not* expecting the deck itself to be in random order. So you can check for "ACE OF SPADES" by applying the same logic that you used to populate the deck: SPADES = 3 (out of 0-3) and ACE = 0 (out of 0-12), so ACE OF SPADES is 3 * 13 + 0. So, just check `is_removed[3 * 13 + 0]`.